# Unable to import city_database dataset from NLTK data in Anaconda Spyder Windows Platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, anaconda, spyder

I have downloaded the NLTK Data Sets using `nltk.download()` into a specific folder path in the D drive say D:\ABC\xyz. I have set this path in the environment variable 'NLTK_DATA'. I have included this path in the python program using `nltk.data.path.append("D:\ABC\xyz")`

Now when I include the statement:
`from nltk.corpus import city_database` I get the error 'cannot import name 'city_database''

This dataset resides in the path:D:\ABC\xyz\nltk_data\corpora\city_database but I am unable to find the right syntax to import this dataset.

Answer (score 2):

The `city_database` is not a corpus but a database for module `nltk.sem.chat80`.

You can access it by calling `nltk.sem.chat80.sql_demo()`. It is just a demo so it prins the database instead of returning it as a list. If you need to do anything more sophisticated look at the docs at

http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.sem.html?highlight=chat80#module-nltk.sem.chat80

For instance to get it as a dict you can query the database this way:

```
capitals = {
    country:city for city, country in nltk.sem.chat80.sql_query(
        "corpora/city_database/city.db",
        "SELECT City, Country FROM city_table"
    )
}
```

But in fact it is rather example of use of the library than usefull dataset,
as it is small and outdated (for instance Moscow is listed as capital of Soviet Union).

Comment: Thanks Jakub for the reply :). I would have upvoted but don't have the necessary points to do so. Would you recommend a better way to identify cities in text using nltk?